# React Native - Won't navigate to a newly created file

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I already have a react-native project which I cloned and running successfully.

I added a new file to the project and tried to link that page using a button from another page with, `this.props.navigation.navigate('DisplayHomeScreen');`

I couldn't link the 'DisplayHomeScreen.js'.

But when I link a page which was already there, the navigate function is working fine.

Here is the simple code of DisplayHomeScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class DisplayHomeScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Display Home</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayHomeScreen;
```

Comment: Hi @NSR. We need some more information to help you with your problem. Have you linked your new screen to the router? Are you getting an error or just seeing nothing? Please post the code of your router and of the component where you're calling navigate

Comment: I'm sorry. My bad. I haven't added the new screen to the router.
Thanks for replying

Comment: No problem. So all working then?

Comment: It's a pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

As your **code snippet is insufficient to identify** the problem.can you please share your navigation stack.Well at spot I  can/ recommend doing.

1. yarn install (if you are using yarn as a package manager)
2. react-native link
3. close metro bundle
4. restart app